# How to force a specific order for retrieving the images from the hard disk using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsfilemanager

How to force a specific order for retrieving the files from the hard disk, given the below code and that the files in the hard disk are images.
How the below code can be modified so that the retrieval of the images must follow a specific order even if the order in the hard disk is changing due to sorting issues, for example, now the files in theHD are sorted by name..few seconds earlier the sorting changed to be via date or something.

In other words, how to force, programmatically, the retrieval of the files to be always in alphabetical order or any other condition

**code**

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
NSString *pred = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SOME TEXT 'iconxxx%@x.png' ", acx];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:pred];
NSArray *onlys = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

Comment: "if the order in the hard disk" there is no order. It's like a key/value order, like a dictionary. If you think about it, it's path, you can't have twice a file with the same path. You'd override it. You choose yourself how to order it. Alphabetically, etc.

Comment: @Larme thx would you please re-read the question, I modified it

Comment: See [contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1414584-contentsofdirectoryatpath?language=occ) "The order of the files in the returned array is undefined.". The files on the hard disk are not sorted by name or date. The Finder app sorts the files.

Comment: Sort yourself keeping the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFilemanager` is not responsible to sort the file listings. After filtering with your predicate, you just sort the array. Typically using `localizedStandardCompare` to sort like Finder or any other file manager.

```
// sort the filtered array
NSArray *sorted = [onlys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```